# Can i upload managed package to Appexchange using migration tool?

Tags: appexchange, migration-tool

Can we upload a managed package to appexchange using migration tool? What is the target name?

I found this  [build.xml](https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/CumulusCI/blob/master/build/build.xml) and there is a target for deploying managed package but haven't tried.

Could somebody let me know if any one had any experience on using migration tool to upload managed package

Answer (score 1):

No, the migration tool only allows you to modify metadata in orgs you control. It can't be used to automate uploads to the App Exchange. The build target for managed packages allows you to install a package into an org you have access to.

Comment: If not appexchange, Can we just upload the package using migration tool? and  pass the url to other developers? Can I do this using ANT?

Comment: Thanks so much for your time in looking into this question.

Comment: Any package that you can distribute by URL has been uploaded to the App Exchange. This isn't possible with the toolkit. You can, however, modify the contents of a package and create new packages, but you'll still have to distribute the contents, and not an install URL.